# Please identify a resistor - it looks like the stripes are brown, black (or blue), brown, gold

Tags: resistors, identification

The resistor in my equipment (amplifier) is burnt out, but I have found a photograph of the resistor I need to replace. It is hard to identify a replacement. The resistor is quite large and matt green. Looks like the stripes are brown, black (or blue), brown, gold. Can anyone help?

[image: Resistor to be replaced]

[image: Burnt out resistor]

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know the size of the burnt resistor? That is proportional to the power rating, and from the lenght of it people could make better guesses at which power rating it actually has.

Comment: it is around 150/200 mm

Comment: Just FYI - for the resistor in the lower photo to become as burned as it is, then there has been a major overload - but that will have been caused by a problem *somewhere else*. Just replacing the resistor won't solve the underlying problem (whatever that is).

Comment: Thanks - I think I have addressed the cause - a mis-seated valve

Comment: "*it is around 150/200 mm*" There's some miscommunication somewhere. The actual resistor *body* can't be 15-20cm long. Perhaps you are reporting the length including the component leads (wires), which is not what was meant in the earlier comment which asked about the resistor size. Can you measure the resistor body length & diameter, preferably to the nearest mm (you seem to have an equivalent undamaged resistor you can measure, as seen in the upper photo), and add that information into the question, please? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - the burnt out resistor is 21mm other green power resistor nearby seem to be around 24mm.

Comment: Most of the 100 Ohms 7W resistors I found on Mouser had 24 mm or 26 mm, yours is either 7W or slightly more than that. I would have a 10W in there and make sure that I fix what caused it to get all burnt like that.

Comment: Great - thanks!!!

Comment: what copper traces are on the two leads? that is the primary heat-removal path.

Comment: There are many 10W 100ohm power resistors on mouser. The main difference between them seems to be voltage - how do I know which 10W 100ohm resistor is suitable... and how do I know what voltage is required?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the brown black brown gold one? That is 10e1 +/- 5%, or plainly 100 +/- 5%. From the size and looks of it, that is a power resistor, and my guess is that it is rated for 5W or 10W.

Comment: I assume it would be a big problem if I replaced the resistor with one with the wrong power rating? Is there any way of knowing for sure what to replace it with?

Comment: The power rating is how much it can dissipate, suppose the original one was rated for 8W, substituting it for a 10W or more would be ok, if it can handle 10W or more they can deal with just 8W. But using a 5W instead of the 8W would definitely make it burn.

Comment: OK so I would need to get a replacement resistor with the highest likely rating (based on size as discussed in the previous comments)